# To trail every div in a dom using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have to trail the divs in a DOM which height is less then 100px. so for that i use each function. but it didnt work.
this is the code i tried..

```
jquery('div').each(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).height()< 40){
    jQuery(this).remove();
  }
```

The HTML for the divs looks like this:

```
<div class="foo"></div> 
<div class="foo"></div> 
<div class="foo"></div> 
<div class="foo"></div> 
<div class="goo"></div> 
<div class="loo"></div> 
<div class="goo"></div> 
<div class="loo"></div>
```

and the css for each class causes different heights.

Comment: Could you please show us the html of a typical div in this instance?

Comment: How didn't it work? Did you get a Javascript error (likely yes, if the code you posted is the exact code you used)? Did you get unexpected results? If the latter is the case, what happened and what did you expect to happen that didn't?

Comment: <div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="goo"></div>
<div class="loo"></div>
<div class="goo"></div>
<div class="loo"></div>
and the css are for the HTML is different height as the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
jQuery('div').each(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).height()< 40){
    jQuery(this).remove();
  }
});
```

You have to add in the end `})` and capitalize `Q` in `jquery`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Sotiris/Xnhun/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).height()< 40) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are on the right track, but the bracket and parenthesis are in the wrong order.

Comment: Your closing parenthesis should be *after* the curly brace. Also, you need a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensetive. Change `jquery` to `jQuery`.

Also, you have to run the code after the page has loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('div').each(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).height() < 40){
      jQuery(this).remove();
    }
  });

});
```

You can also use the `filter` method to filter out the elements to remove:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('div').filter(function(){
    return jQuery(this).height() < 40;
  }).remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy you have not closed your each function

```
jquery('div').each(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).height()< 40){
    jQuery(this).remove();
  })
```

i have tried...
this code in fiddle

```
 $('div').each(function(index){
    alert(index);
   })
```